# Dickey-Fuller test for ARX models

Tags: time-series, references, stationarity, autoregressive, augmented-dickey-fuller

I can't find any source that mentions whether or not the Dickey-Fuller test (or the augmented one) is suitable for an auto-regressive model with exogenous inputs. Is there any literature source for that?